# Linear functions in Lenstra's algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, convex-optimization

I'm working on implementing [Lenstra's algorithm](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/presentations/Lenstra81.pdf). At the bottom of p.5 (at "construct $n+1$ linear functions"), he says to constrain each $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by its value on each of $n+1$ vectors (namely, $v_0,\dots,v_n$). My question pertains to what Lenstra does after optimizing on each $g_i$ (eq.(16)'s paragraph).

Why should replacing $v_i$ with $x$ satisfying eq.(16) (that is, $\lvert g_i(x-v_j)\rvert>\frac{3}{2}\lvert g_i(v_i-v_j\rvert$) cause $vol(v_0,\dots,v_n)=\det(v_i-v_0)_{i\in[n]}$ to increase by a factor of $\frac{3}{2}$? I guess I'm not seeing exactly what about this choice of $g_i$ makes it so desirable to optimize over.

Is there a determinant identity that I'm missing that solves this? It seems that were $v_i$ to be replaced by $v_i=x$, the angles between some vectors could become quite slim, causing the determinant to perhaps even decrease.

Comment: did you implement and open source it?

Comment: My application only ended up needing 1 and 2 dimensions, so I got those cases working and never got higher dimensions to quite work. It is currently not on github but I suppose I could try to get it up there at some point.

Comment: Can you put it on Github? I need a 3 dimensional implementation.

Comment: It can currently be found as `Znpoints` in https://math.berkeley.edu/~zstier/icosahedral/convex.py but it still does not support dimension > 2. However hopefully it's a good start and can successfully be debugged to work in all dimensions. If you manage to get it to work I will gladly incorporate your code if you'd like, of course with due acknowledgements/citation.

Comment: It appears I need only for 2dimensions like yourself. You have tested that it works for 2D. correct?

Comment: I did do some unit testing, and the application I used it for ultimately was getting the correct answers, but I'd still advise double-checking just to be certain.

Comment: Is there an user manual of sorts? like a commentary of what each function does?

Comment: https://math.berkeley.edu/~zstier/icosahedral/ contains a short description of what most of the functions do (I believe I wrote descriptions for all of the functions one could plausibly want to call directly, but not necessarily all of the helper methods)

Answer (score 2):

As a partial answer, Equation 16 is a condition that leads to convergence. The replacement follows from maximization by a method that seems similar to LP rounding. I have not ran the numbers, but a factor of 3/2 seems plausible for that technique.

I suppose convergence is chosen as a criterion because it doesn't know where to optimize to. I think it related to Lipschitz convergence. In practice, it is probably good to add a constant regularization term. Iterative convergence is often very fast, usually exponentially so. Basically, this method minimizes the convex hulls surrounding the solution, thereby simplifying the problem. Yes, when taken as rays, this method aligns the rays to the target.

I am not aware of any relevant discriminant identities beyond the obvious one of Gaussian elimination.

Comment: Maybe other measures of curve similarity, like frechet distance, are more suitable. But this is probably overkill. That's the point, it doesn't matter much what you use, as long as you converge. I recommend a simple iteration method, like Newton Raphson or Euler.